# How to safely add power switch to power strip?

Tags: electrical

I have two powered monitor speakers on my desk. Each speaker has a power rocker switch on the back and it's a nuisance I would like to circumvent. I would like to add an extended power switch to a 3-plug power strip that I can be secured to an accessible area of my desk. I don't want to worry about it causing an electrical fire when I'm away from my desk.

I'm thinking I could install an shallow electrical box with a light switch to control the power. How dangerous is something like this? Is there a better way of doing it? I have plenty of experience doing electrical work.

Answer (score 2):

Those power strips are available with switches built in, in fact I have several...

Answer (score 1):

Does the power strip have a knockout on it?  Just run 1/2" EMT conduit from the power strip to the switch, which you put in a short handy-box.

If the power strip doesn't have a knockout or if it's plastic, then junk the power strip and stick a 4" square steel box there. EMT to the switch, 2 receptacles on the cover (4 sockets) and a hefty power cord with a proper strain relief (which are readily available at any local electrical supply).   Get a proper cord by going SNIP to a 14AWG extension cord, or just buy cord-with-plug from McMaster-Carr.  Then go to a real electrical supply house for a proper strain relief for a knockout.